# Should I use past perfect here or not?

Tags: past-perfect

A query message to an online seller:

> (hyperlink to the product)
>
> Wanna buy but I'm not quite sure if it's genuine or not cz I saw a review by one of your buyers, **he/he'd uploaded** a photo taken on this device which is very noisy and quite lame for a 41 mp camera.

Should I use past perfect after 'I saw a review' ? as past perfect follows past simple.

for example,

> I was having my dinner when you *had called*

Comment: your example sounds weird it means that while you were eating, the person had finished calling you it would be better to use past simple while you were eating a person called and you did not finish your dinner

Comment: yeah that's what I meant. By you'd called I mean I could not pick the call up

Comment: commas are mandatory by the way. You were supposed to put a comma after **while you were eating** otherwise people might think you're a cannibal :p

Comment: The whole style of the comment is ultra casual and rather rude. Nobody will care about the subtle difference between "uploaded" and "had uploaded".

Comment: yeah @James after all it's a complaint. It's oughta be rude 

Comment: @user422389 I agree with James K. Scammers often include spelling and grammatical mistakes in correspondence, because people that don't notice stuff like that are easier to fool. If the vendor is selling fake goods, he will be delighted that your message is so poorly written, and will make every effort to get you to buy. If, however, the supplier is genuine and the reviewer is bogus (yes, that happens too), he will look at your message and decide that you probably can't afford a 41Mp camera, or are an accomplice of the bogus reviewer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **was** instead of **is** if you want to use past perfect, if you use **is** past simple is fine but I am not a native

Comment: where should I use was instead of is?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use past perfect because the uploading occurred before the seeing, and the seeing is in the past.

> I saw a review by one of your buyers: he had uploaded a photo...

The eating example is not the same thing at all. You are talking about two things that happened at the same time - the eating and the calling - so it should be:

> I was having my dinner when you called

If the eating had occurred before the call (which is in the past), the eating would be in the past perfect:

> I had eaten when you called